# Draper: Using decorators with related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use the ProductDecorator with related objects (products)?

Controller:

```
def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Product decorator:

```
decorate :product

def somevalue
   'somevalue'
end
```

View:

```
<%= render partial: 'list_item', collection: @category.products %>
```

Partial:

```
<%= list_item.somevalue %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `ProductDecorator.decorate` on the `Product`s  collection like this:

```
# View
<%= render partial: 'list_item', collection: ProductDecorator.decorate(@category.products) %>
```